# MongoDB pymongo

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

Есть код:

```
id = input('id=')
username = input('username=')
db.users.save( {'id':id, 'username':username, 'date':  strftime("%d-%m- 
%Y%H:%M:%S", gmtime())} )
user = list(db.users.find({}, {'_id': 0}))
sarr = [str(a) for a in user]
print('\n\n'.join(sarr))
```

Его вывод:

> ```
> id=123
> username=den
> {'username': 'den', 'date': '26-07-2018 11:56:54', 'id': '123'}
> ```

Как например вывести такое:

```
username: den, date: 26-07-2018 11:56:54, id: 123
```

Comment: Может,  так: `print(', '.join('{0}: {1}'.format(k, v) for k, v in user[2].items()))`

Comment: @Anton Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\bd\bot.py", line 28, in <module>
    print(', '.join('{0}: {1}'.format(k, v) for k, v in user[2].items()))
IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: Гм, а если 2 заменить на -1? Вообще, я исходил из того, что user[2] - это словарь, тут могу ошибаться, отвечал я как вывести словарь.

Comment: а так работает , спасибо

Comment: @Anton вот только оно выводит последне добавленные данные а не все с базы